# Mockery Laravel Elequent chained queries

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I have a question regarding mockery in combination with Laravel.
I have sucessfully created a mockery object to mock all the public static methods such as where and find on the elequent model instance.
`$userMock = \Mockery::mock('alias:App\Models\User');`

This works great, however testing chained queries like I ran into some issues:
`User::where("name", "test")->first()`

The only solution I could find is to use mock the demeter chain using: [http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
So for example:
`$userMock->shouldReceive('where->first')->andReturn($user);`

But I would like to test the arguments that are provided to the where query as well:
`$userMock->shouldReceive("where")->with("slug", "test")->andReturn($user);`

But that is not really working since it should return the Elequent builder, any ideas how I can test this properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
$userMock->shouldReceive('where')
            ->with("slug", "test")
            ->andReturn(Mockery::self())
            ->shouldReceive("first")
            ->andReturn($user);
```

Using Mockery::self you can complete the chain.